# code viewing on website - for users to copy

Tags: html

Does some knows how to view a html code into a page. Meaning that the users can copy the code viewing on a page.!
Can it be done by a simple way for showing it into the page. ( by page I mean on the website! )

Comment: what to do mean by view?

Comment: Copy your html and insert into a `<pre>` or `<code>` tag?

Comment: I have tried the <pre> and <code> but the < in the <input type=""> is creating and showing the box!! -> If I remove the < than the codes are viewing... I need something that the users can copy and paste.. not adding any more codes!

Answer (score 0):

IF you mean sourcecode.. well the easiest I can think of is just geting innerHtml

javascript: `document.body.innerHTML`

Comment: Not the source code.. If you get into at website where they are demonstrating at function for at code than you can see that you are able to copy that function and added into your html.page

Answer (score 0):

You have to apply HTML entities to it to convert it to plain text and prevent its execution... this is the faster way: http://htmlentities.net/

Comment: Yes... Do you some another pages!!

Comment: Excuse me? What do you mean?